# Smoothscroll without anchors

Tags: jquery, scroll, smoothing

okay I know how to smooth scroll to an anchor but how do I smooth scroll a certain static amount (ie. 300px) every time I click a certain object until I reach the end of my page. I can do this once but how bout doing it over and over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var pixelsToMove = 50;

$('.myButton').click(function () {
    var currentScrollTopValue = $('#container').scrollTop();

    $('#container').scrollTop(currentScrollTopValue + pixelsToMove);

});
```

https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: But that only scrolls once to scroll position 300 how do I repeat that